# R plots: setting the font appears to work differently for barplot and barchart

Tags: r, fonts, bar-chart

So I found out that R plotting has a few quirks (I believe):
I am plotting barplots and can easily change the font to "times new roman" of these plots using par(family="serif", font=1)
However, I also want to plot grouped barplots and the function which is working best for me is the barchart.
Unfortunately, the font refuses to change there with the par(family="serif", font=1) command.

Does anyone have an idea how to change the font in barcharts?

In the example below you can alternatively use the barchart-line to plot or the barplot line to see the effect of par(family="serif", font=1) on the font in both cases.

```
molnames<-c("a")
contactcounts<-c(acounts1,acounts2,acounts3)
d<-data.frame(column1=rep(molnames, each=3),column2=rep(c("1","2","3"), 1), column3=contactcounts)
colour<-c("green", "blue","magenta")
tiff(file="./TEST.tiff", res=1000, width = 8, height = 8,units='in')
par(family="serif", font=1)
barchart(column3 ~ column1,ylab="Y test", groups=column2, d, auto.key = list(columns = 3),  par.settings=list(superpose.polygon=list(col=colour)))
barplot(contactcounts)
dev.off()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`barplot()` comes under Base graphics in R and `barchart()` comes in Lattice graphics. The lattice plots donot use `par()` settings. They use grid graphics settings.

You can set their values either using `trellis.par.set()` function in which you provide parameter values as list. The grid parameter values can be set to `grid.pars` component. A list of valid grid parameters can be see in `get.gpar()` from package `grid`, which also has a `fontfamily` parameter.

```
trellis.par.set("grid.pars" = list(fontfamily="Monaco") )
```

if you see warnings/no change in fonts then define the font family yourself by doing:

```
windowsFonts(Monaco=windowsFont("Monaco"))
trellis.par.set(name="grid.pars", value=list(fontfamily="Monaco"))
barchart(disp~gear)
```

This works for me

Comment: ok, so that explains what is going on. But how do I change the fonts then? I have tried trellis.par.get(family="serif", font=1), but that gives me the following error: Error in trellis.par.get(family = "serif", font = 1) : 
  unused arguments (family = "serif", font = 1)